# Quantum conditional von Neumann entropy - changing system I condition on, i.e. bipartite vs tripartite entropic uncertainty relation with qu. memory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am reading Entropic Uncertainty Relations and their Applications by Patrick J. Coles, Mario Berta, Marco Tomamichel and Stephanie Wehner.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04857

I am trying to reproduce the link between the **bipartite** entropic uncertainty relation with quantum memory, namely
\begin{equation}H(X|B) + H(Z|B)\geq q+H(A|B),\end{equation}
and the **tripartite** one with quantum memory, i.e.
\begin{equation}H(X|B) + H(Z|C)\geq q,\end{equation}
where we have a tripartite system $\rho_{ABC}$, and the $X,Z$ measurements were conducted on party $A$.

In the review they show a simple connection from the tripartite to the bipartite. Namely apply the tripartite inequality to a purification $\rho_{ABC}$ to you bipartite system $\rho_{AB}$. Then just use Eq. (208) (pg. 31), i.e.
\begin{equation}
H(Z|C) = H(Z|B)-H(A|B),
\end{equation}
however, it is **unclear for me how this is true**.

What I've tried so fare: using the definition of condition entropy, this is the same as
\begin{align}
H(ZC)-H(C) &= H(ZB)-H(B)-H(AB)+H(B),\\
H(ZC)-H(C) &= H(ZB)-H(AB).
\end{align}
Now, using that $\rho_{ABC}$ is pure, H(C) = H(AB). Thus these terms cancel out and we're left with (208) being equivalent to
\begin{align}
H(ZC) &= H(ZB),
\end{align}
which surely isn't true in general for any measurement $Z$ on system $A$.

What am I missing? Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: So it seems that all you need is Def. (41) from the paper, the basis invariance property, and that you are looking at a pure tripartite state.